# How do I fix, XMLHttpRequest

Tags: cors

Well here is my `.htaccess` file so far. I'll post it below:

```
AddType text/plain .phps
AddType application/x-tgz .tgz
AddType application/x-chrome-extension .crx
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json .webapp

<filesMatch "^(index|preactalpha)\.html$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
```

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sim2.pokemoninfinite.com/showdown/info?t=1558251232053' from origin 'https://play.pokemonadventures.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I put section 4. in the above section .3 "Add some code".

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

You have to allow requsts from other domains